# Invite the user to make the blockchain transaction from telegram bot

Tags: blockchain, telegram-bot

Is there any way to prompt the user to make a certain transaction to a smart contract with the parameters

I would like it to be as convenient for the user as possible

I tried diplinking metamask - but it seems that there you can not call the function of a smart contract with parameters.

I would also like to build a system so that the user does not need to entrust his funds to a bot.

Is there any possible solutions?